# Table reference in formula breaks excel file

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to use a formula for a cell. Inside the formula I reference a table called `tblTest`. After running the script I try to open the excel file but I get an error, that there are problems with the file and if it should be restored or not. So, it seems like the problem is because I reference a table.

##### Code

```py
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Planung.xlsx")
ws = wb["Zeitplan"]
ws["B6"].value = '=INDEX(FILTER(tblTest,tblTest[Packet]="A"),1)'

wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

##### Reproduction Steps

- Create file called `Planung.xlsx`
- Create sheet called `Zeitplan`
- Create a second sheet and there create a table called `tblTest` with a column called `Packet`
- Run code
- Try open `test.xlsx` (should output error)

##### Edit

What I noticed is that when I set `=tblTest` as the value, I can open the file but in the cell there's the error `#NAME?`. Only when I press onto the cell and press enter in the formula input, it works. It feels like it can't find the table even if it's there.

Comment: 1. have you confirmed the formula by manually entering in a cell? 2. The FILTER function is new and only supported in latest Excel releases so ensure the Excel version testing with does support it. 3. You can remove the '=' from the front so it's entered as text to ensure there are no translation issues. 4. And/or open the 'test.xlsx' file after it's created and view the 'Zeitplan.xml' file to see if the formula is saved in the sheet correctly.

Comment: The `FILTER` function was the problem. It's not in `FORMULAE`